# How to inverse mouse wheel zoom handling in Piccolo2D?

Tags: java, scaling, mousewheel, piccolo

In most applications rotating wheel down descreases the size of scaled objects, while rotating wheel up increases sizes.

In piccolo2d default behavior is reversed:

```
private static void showWorldNode() {
        new PFrame() {

            @Override
            public void initialize() {

                getCanvas().getLayer().addChild(worldNode);

                PMouseWheelZoomEventHandler mouseWheelZoomEventHandler = new PMouseWheelZoomEventHandler();
                mouseWheelZoomEventHandler.zoomAboutMouse();
                getCanvas().addInputEventListener(mouseWheelZoomEventHandler);
            }

        };
    }
```

How to reverse to default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a negative scale factor to reverse the behavior, for example:

```
mouseWheelZoomEventHandler.setScaleFactor(-0.1d);
```

`PMouseWheelZoomEventHandler` calculates the zoom value based on the scale factor and the value of [MouseWheelEvent.getWheelRotation()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelEvent.html#getWheelRotation%28%29) which returns:

> negative values if the mouse wheel was rotated up/away from the user,
>   and positive values if the mouse wheel was rotated down/ towards the
>   user

Here is the relevant code from `PMouseWheelZoomEventHandler`

```
double scale = 1.0d + event.getWheelRotation() * scaleFactor;
```

Comment: Strange, but while scale of `-0.1` worked, scale of `-1` is causing exception when rotating back.

Comment: @SuzanCioc yes, according to the calculation of `scale` mentioned above, `scaleFactor = -1` results in `scale = 0`. `PAffineTransform` protects against zero division for calculation of inverse transform and it throws `PAffineTransformException`.